# Ubuntu VM does not connect to the internet

Tags: networking, server

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a VM under Unraid and everything worked fine until i suddenly couldnt connect via ssh anymore. So i used the VNC Client and searched the error. I first thought its a Hardware issue(it isnt) but my other vms where able to connect to the internet. The ifconfig only shows the Loopback but the virtual networking interface was detected.(checked via ifconfig -a). Is somebody familiar with the issue or has a guess how to fix it?

In between my tries of fixing it it suddenly worked again until i restarted...

Comment: Did you configure the settings on your virtual machine manager? Sometimes you have to enable the virtual connection for it to work correctly.

Comment: Should be enabled